# JSON.parse() returns [object Object], [object Object], [object Object] when deserialized

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

I have this json: `[{"Id":"1", "ZipCode":"00691","City":"Adjuntas","Municipality":"Adjuntas"},{"Id":"2", "ZipCode":"00603","City":"Aguadilla","Municipality":"Aguadilla"},{"Id":"3", "ZipCode":"00674","City":"Manati","Municipality":"Manati"}]`

My problem is deserializing this using javascript's json.parse().

This is what I've tried

```
function OnZipCodeBlur()
{
    var hfZipCodesValue = document.getElementById("<%=hfZipCodesMunicipalitiesCities.ClientID%>").value;
    var zipCode = document.getElementById("<%=tbZipCode.ClientID%>").value;
    alert("serialization: " + hfZipCodesValue);
    var zipCodeDeserialized = JSON.parse(hfZipCodesValue);
    var d = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < zipCodeDeserialized.length; i++)
    {               
        if (zipCodeDeserialized[i].ZipCode == zipCode) 
        {
            document.getElementById('<%=tbCity.ClientID%>').value = zipCodeDeserialized[i].City;
            document.getElementById('<%=tbMunicipality.ClientID%>').value = zipCodeDeserialized[i].Municipality;
            break;
        }
        d += zipCodeDeserialized[i];
    }
    alert("deserialization : " + d);
}
```

`hfZipCodesValue` - holds serialized data
`ZipCode` - holds a zip code.
As you can you see, I have two alerts showing the serialized data and deserialized. The first alert displays correctly and the second just returns [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]. At first I thought that I had to pick an index instead of showing the whole array like I'm doing now but, that's when I realized that it was an array of chars. In other words `d[0] == "["` and `d[1] == 'o'`. Nevermind the if in the for, it never goes in cause of the object results.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you convert an object to a string you get `[object Object]`. Try doing `console.log(zipCodeDeserialized)`

Comment: @MikeC I can see the string with proper values! But how can I iterate through them? is my approach incorrect?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: if I need the ZipCode from that Deserialization I would like to retrieve it by simply doing something like `deserialized[0].ZipCode`. That's what I'm trying to do

Comment: Then what's the problem? You should be able to access that with `zipCodeDeserialized[i].ZipCode`

Comment: I've seen a few examples that do something similar or exact to what I did and they say it works, but it doesn't work in my case

Comment: Never mind... Hate it when something doesn't work, somebody just looks at it and magically works after just looking at it lol